# How can I escape the default router with a real url in laravel

Tags: laravel, url, location-href

In Blade view

```
<a class="media-left" href="{{$chunk->href}}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward">Go</span>
</a>

{{$chunk->href}}=https://www.google.com
```

I got the error href url

```
localhost::8000/://https://www.google.com
```

use `dd($chank)` on the controller

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url()` helper method is used to generate local-site urls. So if you want to insert the https://google.com link, do this:

```
<a class="media-left" href="{{ $chunk->href }}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward">Go</span>
</a>
```

Comment: sorry~I forget to fix the url() when I post !
I use the code as you but I got the error href link!

Comment: @robspin, can you do a `dd( $chunk );` in your controller or at the top of the html and let me know what you get?

Comment: I post the dd() on my post. Can you check for me,please~thanks!

Comment: @robspin, based on what you dumped, this should not be inserting any extra data in front of the url. Can you verify that you removed `url()`, saved, and refreshed the page?

Comment: I find it solved! Maybe I type error ~I refix the href it works~thank for your help!

Comment: I want to ask how can I avoid the error from the refresh errror? I use F5 to refresh my page   though it is mostly normal work well but sometimes it get the error refresh just like this time. It's  so  annoying and wastes so much time to debug the nonexistent error.